# What Polish village is named in this document?

Tags: palaeography, poland, jewish

[This draft registration card](http://sharing.ancestry.com/6909956?h=75e1ad&utm_campaign=bandido-webparts&utm_source=post-share-modal&utm_medium=share-url) lists a birth location of what looks like Soodlikof, Poland, but I cannot find any record of such a place.  This relative was a Jew born in 1888, so the location is likely a shtetl.  Other documents only list "Russia" as the birth place.

[image: draft card]

Comment: If you can identify the friends, associates, neighbors (FAN) and/or siblings of your relatives in the WWI or WWII Draft Registration cards, see if any of them were born in the same town -- that might turn up alternate spellings or the name of the town in a different handwriting which is easier to read.  If you find more samples, you can add them to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good resource is [The Geographical Dictionary of the Kingdom of Poland and other Slavic Countries](http://dir.icm.edu.pl/Slownik_geograficzny/)

Looking for names similar to Soodlikov, one finds *Sudilowka* on p 550 of volume XI which tells one to look at the entry *Sudylków*. *Sudylków* is found on p 553 of volume XI where it is described over a two columns. *Sudylków* is on the river Kosecka. In 1870 there were 422 buildings in the town and 1384 residents of which about 40% were Jewish. The town was about 120 km from Żytomierz.

Answer (score 6):

I think it might be Sudlikov. There's a Sudilkov, Ukraine, which gets more matches on Google (see http://grossmanproject.net/sudilkov_jewish_history.htm). But Sudlikov shows up too (eg http://www.antiquejewishbooks.net/522.html). So I'm not sure if they were the same place.